# JCarouselLite Smooth Vertical Scrolling

Tags: jquery, vertical-scrolling, jcarousellite, ticker, smooth-scrolling

Sorry if this question has been asked before, but I was unable to find the exact answer I was looking for.

I need to make a vertical text ticker that moves smoothly, with no discernable pauses, and repeats indefinitely.

I found JCarouselLite, and got everything looking how I want.

However, if I set the "auto" interval to 1, or even 0.01, there is still a pause inbetween each movement. I've also set the easing to "linear" to remove that from the equation.

Next, I tried setting the scroll to more items total, and a longer duration, to minimize the pauses. With the duration set to 18000ms and 51 items, it looks great. One problem, it delays for 18000ms before getting started the first time, and every subsequent time.

Page here:
https://secure.awarenesslife.com/tickertest.cfm

Code 1 here (single-scroll version):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".academyCarousel").jCarouselLite({
        vertical: true,
        hoverPause: false,
        visible: 15,
        easing: 'linear',
        auto: 0.001,
        speed: 800,
        scroll: 1
    });
});
</script>
```

Code 2 here (multi-scroll version):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".academyCarousel").jCarouselLite({
        vertical: true,
        hoverPause: false,
        visible: 15,
        easing: 'linear',
        auto: 0.001,
        speed: 18000,
        scroll: 51
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you ever work this out?